# Removing specific value from SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Hi i currently have this column in a SQL table, i would like to remove all value of the last bracket

Current Column

```
    Column xxx
    Banana
    Apple(3yy)(Rev 1)
    Pear(5zx)(Rev 3)
    orange(9iz)(Minor 5)
    Cow(7iz)(Roaring 5)
```

Desired Column

```
    Column xxx
    Banana
    Apple(3yy)
    Pear(5zx)
    orange(9iz)
    Cow(7iz)
```

I am willing to write a package in SSIS or do a SQL script to remove the values in the bracket. Any advice given would be largely appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If possible I would export the table to excel and make the changes and get it back into the database.

Comment: What if you had `Banana(3yy)` Would it be reduced to `Banana`? In other words, is the rule: Remove everything in the last set of parenthesis? Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Billinkc: yes, if i had Banana(3yy) it would become Banana

The King: I would require it to be a constant as I have to schedule the process

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0ab2/8)

No need for an SSIS package unless you have oversimplified your problem. An update statement is all you need.

```
UPDATE
    S
SET
    Column1 = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(S.Column1)) > 0
        THEN REVERSE(RIGHT(REVERSE(S.Column1), LEN(S.Column1) - CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(S.Column1))))
        ELSE S.Column1
    END 
FROM
    dbo.Source AS S;
```

My logic is thus

- Reverse the string to find that first, which is truly the last, parenthesis `(`
- If the position is 0, there is no work to be done.
- Otherwise, for the reversed string, take the last N characters of the string (everything after the parenthesis) then reverse that again to put it back in order.

Comment: The query is not working on my end and SQLFiddle

Comment: Thanks your answer worked, i copied and pasted the wrong field :)

Comment: Downvoter, could you help me understand the vote so that I may improve my answer?

Comment: Really, downvoters could you help me understand the votes. It solved the problem and I explain the approach so it's not just a "this query fixes it" answer.